# How to make a 2D array in python with variables

Tags: python, arrays

I have been tasked to create a generation model for school, and I need to set two variables, each referencing each other. This is what I have got so far:

```
global Gen
NBR = 0
Gen = 0
print ("You have chosen option 3, Run The Model.")
#adults*birthrate
for i in range (newGensToModel):
    NBR += 1
    Gen += 1
    #Unrelated  newSen = gen0Sen * survRate


elements = []

elements.append([])
elements.append([])

elements[0].append(newAd[int(newJuvs)])
elements[0].append(newJuvs[int(newAd * NBR * birthRate)])


print(elements[0][0])

for row in elements:
    for column in row:
        print(column, end="")
    print(end="\n")
```

This gives the error:

```
elements[0].append(newAd[int(newJuvs)], newJuvs[int(newAd * NBR * birthRate)])
NameError: name 'newAd' is not defined
```

Basically, all I want to know, is how do I make newAd a variable in the 2D array.

Comment: where is newD coming from? Also newJuvs,NBR  and birthRate? I think a tutorial would be a good start http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: Since `newAd` is undefined, you should provide more code to show where this should be defined.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you you haven't defined newAd (you also haven't defined newJuvs in this example).
Once it's created, you'll be able to append it to your list.